# Tableau: Publish "Dashboards Only" using tabcmd

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to automate publishing of Tableau dashboards and while there's an option "Dashboards Only" when publishing using UI there doesn't seem to be such option in tabcmd.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, there is not an option for 'Dashboards Only'. The only option regarding tabs is

```
--tabbed

When a workbook with tabbed views is published, each sheet becomes a tab that viewers 
can use to navigate through the workbook. Note that this setting will override any 
sheet-level security.
```

You can only show all tabs or hide all but the first tab using `tabcmd`

Comment: How do I hide all but first tab?